# ¿Cómo saber cuando una app se cierra?

Tags: java, android

Quiero saber si es posible saber cuando alguna app que se está utilizando se deja de utilizar: "se cierra". He encontrado un método pero sólo sirve para saber cuándo ***mi*** app se cierra, por lo tanto no me sirve, pero se los muestro:

```
public void onTrimMemory(final int level) {
if (level == ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN) {
    //SCREEN IS NOT SHOWING
}
```

De la pregunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33818406/how-to-detected-if-application-is-closed

Comment: "Quiero saber si es posible saber cuando alguna app que se está utilizando se deja de utilizar: "se cierra". He encontrado un método pero sólo sirve para saber cuándo mi app se cierra, por lo tanto no me sirve"

ah?? como??

Comment: No entiendo muy claro su comentario, pero querrá preguntarme a que me refiero en mi pregunta. Si es así: me refiero a que quiero saber cuando el usuario salga de un o app que no es la mía y me interesa porque mi app fue la que lo envió a la otra app.

Comment: se me ocurren 2 formas de llevarlo a cabo, uno es que cuando la aplicación se cierre, mande un intent avisando a la otra aplicación.
pero esto debería implementarse en cada método onDestroy() de la aplicación.
la otra opción es consultar desde la aplicación que esta corriendo si la otra aplicación esta activa. y esta consulta debe realizarse antes de mandar cualquier dato para iniciar la comunicarse (creo que este link puede ayudar para esta opción https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/01/can-i-use-this-intent.html)

Comment: Gracias su comentario me ayudo a inspirarme para realizar una búsqueda mas profunda y encontré mi respuesta muchas gracias.

Comment: De nada, ¿puedes compartir la url de la respuesta para futuros usuarios con tu situación?

Comment: Ya he publicado una repuesta del código que obtuve y edite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### **Para definir que aplicaciones se están ejecutando en un Android.**

Se usa  [ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.html), por ejemplo podemos obtener que aplicaciones se estan ejecutando, por medio de un BroadcastReciber o el click a un boton llamar este método el cual determina que aplicaciones estan ejecutandose (imprime nombre de proceso);

```
public void obtenerAplicaciones(Context context){
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List l = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
    Iterator i = l.iterator();
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    while(i.hasNext()) {
        ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo info = (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo)(i.next());
        try {
            CharSequence c = pm.getApplicationLabel(pm.getApplicationInfo(info.processName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
            Log.d("Aplicaciones", c.toString());
            //runningApplications.add(c.toString());
        }catch(Exception e) {
            Log.d("Aplicaciones", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Es importante comentar que si la aplicación esta en "Background" se considera como activa, si la eliminas completamente ya no aparecería en la lista.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

#### **Para determinar si una aplicación se esta ejecutando en un dispositivo Android.**

Para determinar esto puedes usar también ActivityManager, como ejemplo un método el cual recibe el contexto y determina si la aplicación esta instalada:

```
private boolean ejecutandoAplicacion(Context context, String packagename) {
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    for(int i = 0; i < procInfos.size(); i++)
    {
        if(procInfos.get(i).processName.equals(packagename))
        {
            return true; //Esta activa.
        }
    }
    return false; //Esta cerrada.
}
```

un ejemplo de como llamar el método anterior:

```
  if (ejecutandoAplicacion(getApplicationContext(), "com.mydominio.stackoverflow")) {
     Log.i("Aplicacion", "La aplicación esta ejecutandose!");
  } else {
    Log.i("Aplicacion", "La aplicación esta cerrada.");
 }
```

Se tiene la misma consideración, una aplicación en "background" se considera que esta activa, esto si el sistema operativo no la ha cerrado.

Answer (score 2):

La repuesta es este codigo:

```
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
    java.util.List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    for(int i = 0; i < procInfos.size(); i++)
    {
        if(procInfos.get("Aqui se coloca el nombre de paquete de la aplicacion").processName.equals(i3)) 
        {
           //Aquí se obtiene si es que se esta ejecutando
        }else{
           //Aquí se obtiene que no se esta utilizando
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Indica si su aplicación se está ejecutando en FOREGROUND

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo#IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND_SERVICE

```
    private boolean isExecute() {
            ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> processInfos = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();

            for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo info : processInfos) {

                if (BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID.equalsIgnoreCase(info.processName) && ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND == info.importance)
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
}
```

Comment: Traduce tu pregunta estas en **SO en español**